# How to stop downloading file in Skydrive API

Tags: objective-c, onedrive

After starting downloading a file, How to stop downloading file? I Initiate the download like this:

```
[docDirSkyDRive  appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@ ",[[FilesFromSkyDrive objectAtIndex:indexPath] objectForKey:@"name"]]];
NSMutableString *downloadPath=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[downloadPath appendFormat:@"%@/content",[[FilesFromSkyDrive objectAtIndex:indexPath] objectForKey:@"id"]];
[self.liveClient downloadFromPath:downloadPath delegate:self userState:@"download"];
```

This is my code snippet for downloading files, but don't know how to stop the downloading files once started.

Comment: In .NET, I would do an async download and stop the async thread upon request. I would assume that something like this is available on iOS, too.

Comment: BTW, in [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh913536.aspx) there is a delegate that is called upon progress. Maybe you can cancel from within that delegate?

Comment: They didnt gave any method to cancel in delegate.@UweKeim

Comment: Yes, I saw that :-) Would it as a bad-practice be at least possible to throw an exception to exit the download and catch it somewhere up in the call stack instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

```
[docDirSkyDRive  appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@ ",[[FilesFromSkyDrive    objectAtIndex:indexPath] objectForKey:@"name"]]];
NSMutableString *downloadPath=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[downloadPath appendFormat:@"%@/content",[[FilesFromSkyDrive objectAtIndex:indexPath] objectForKey:@"id"]];
LiveOperation *opperation = [self.liveClient downloadFromPath:downloadPath delegate:self userState:@"download"];
```

then you can cancel this opperation using `[opperation cancel];`